# Why app archive failed with custom frameworks in iOS, swift, xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, app-store, archive, xcode9, swift-custom-framework

I'm creating an **iOS app** which use **my own custom framework**. Can `build, run` with real **iOS devices** & with **simulators**.

But if I try to **Archive** the project for `App Store` it gives me **Error** says :

> ```
> the functions & classes are unresolved identifier
> ```

I have used so many third party frameworks (not the cocoa pods) (ex: facebook or any) and can user properly from build, run to archive. But why can't we use our own `framework` for `archive`.

> NOTE: just drag and drop my custom framework to my iOS project and
>   selected copy items if needed.

Any reason for this and how can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this. but there may be other ways as well. **this is open to any answer**.

**I followed below steps :**

- In your custom framework project ( cocoa touch framework project ) ,
  select your **Project** in **Targets**.
- Then search for `Skip install`.
- Change it into `NO`.
- Then archive your custom framework. ( make sure to select `Generic
  iOS Device` ) as target device.
- Export it to where you want.
- Then use it with your project.

**Hope this will help to you**